# Closing side thread before closing the main form

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I'm making a GUI application with windows forms in Visual Studio .NET 2010 using `C#`.
I have multiple threads, for example:

1. Thread that is pinging target device to make sure the connection is not lost
2. A thread that requests and receives measurement results from the device
3. A thread that is constantly updating the main form with these results. This thread invokes changes in main form controls using `Control.Invoke()`.
   My goal: I want to make sure that form is closed properly when user presses (x) on the main form. That means I want my connection to close, all side threads to terminate etc.
   I'm trying to use `FormClosing` event. 
   There I set KillThreads flag to true and wait for side threads to terminate. There is a check in each, something like

```cs
if(KillThreads)
    return;
```

But there is an issue.
If I try to wait for all threads to be terminated

```
for(;;)
if(ActiveSideThreads == 0)
    break;
closeConnection();
```

the thread N3 freezes blocked by `Invoke()` call;
Sure it is, because the main gui thread is in infinite loop.
So the form closing is delayed forever.

If I implement before-close operations as a thread procedure 4, and make a new thread in FromClosing event handler,
form closes immediately, before the thread 4 termination, and `Invoke()` throws an error - t. 4 could not close thread 3 in time.
If I add `Join(), Invoke()` calls are blocked again, and thread 3 is never terminated, so thread 4 waits forever.

What should I do?
Is there some way to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you are closing main form this mean you are closing application, am I right? So take a look at the System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit() method, it stops all message loops all all running threads before exit

Comment: Why do you want/need to wait for those threads to exit before closing the form?

Comment: also you can keep thread object in list and before closing main form use `[thread-object]. kill()`. or something like that

Comment: @Damiien - the usual reason why developers are forced into these contortions is the practice of reading/writing/calling from secondary threads and so reference data that is going to be deallocated when the form closes, but before the OS gets to stop the secondary threads.

Comment: @sll, I need my threads to be closed before the main form, because some of them use Invoke()

Comment: @Rev, one of the threads performs communication with external device, which is generally command send/receive, so if the thread is killed in the middle of a command transmission (eg 1 byte of 3), it can make the device stick. So I prefer not to use brute force

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever, Martin is right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off decide whether or not you really need to be using `Invoke` at all. It is, and has been for a while now, my opinion that `Invoke` is one of the most overused techniques for causing an action to occur on the UI thread after it has been initiated from a worker thread. An alternative is to create some type of message object in the worker thread describing the action that needs to be done on the UI thread and place it into a shared queue. The UI thread will then poll this queue on some interval using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and cause each action to occur. This has several advantages.

- It breaks the tight coupling between the UI and worker threads that `Invoke` imposes.
- It puts the responsibility of updating the UI thread on the UI thread where it should belong anyway.
- The UI thread gets to dictate when and how often the update should take place.
- There is no risk of the UI message pump being overrun as would be the case with the marshaling techniques initiated by the worker thread.
- The worker thread does not have to wait for an acknowledgement that the update was performed before proceeding with its next steps (ie. you get more throughput on both the UI and worker threads).
- It is a *lot* easier to handle shutdown operations since you can pretty much eliminate all race conditions that would normally be present when requesting worker threads to gracefully terminate.

Of course, `Invoke` is very useful and there are many reasons to keep using this approach. If you do decide to keep using `Invoke` then read more.

One idea is to set the `KillThreads` flags in the `Form.Closing` event and then cancel closing the form by setting `FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel = true`. You may want to let the user know that a shutdown has been requested and is in progress. You may want to disable some of the controls on the form so new actions cannot be initiated. So basically we are signaling that a shutdown has been requested, but are deferring the closing of the form until the worker threads have shutdown first. To do this you may want to start a timer that periodically checks to see if the worker threads have ended and if they have then you can call `Form.Close`.

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
  private Thread WorkerThread;
  private volatile bool KillThreads = false;

  private void YourForm_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs args)
  {
    // Do a fast check to see if the worker thread is still running.
    if (!WorkerThread.Join(0))
    {
      args.Cancel = true; // Cancel the shutdown of the form.
      KillThreads = true; // Signal worker thread that it should gracefully shutdown.
      var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
      timer.AutoReset = false;
      timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
      timer.Interval = 1000;
      timer.Elapsed = 
        (sender, args) =>
        {
          // Do a fast check to see if the worker thread is still running.
          if (WorkerThread.Join(0)) 
          {
            // Reissue the form closing event.
            Close();
          }
          else
          {
            // Keep restarting the timer until the worker thread ends.
            timer.Start();
          }
        };
      timer.Start();
    }
  }    
}
```

The code above calls `Join`, but it specifies a timeout of 0 which causes the `Join` call to return immediately. This should keep the UI pumping messages.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped a lot. I will follow your advice and make some to-do sequence for GUI thread. I should restructure the program, obviously. But for now my problem was solved by adding Join(100) in the FormClose procedure which creates new thread to perform the clean-up=)

Comment: And adding one more try/catch

Answer (score 1):

I would have a top level exception handler in your thread that's performing the Invoke, that swallows the exceptions arising from `Invoke` if it discovers `KillThreads` is true. Then all you need is for the main thread to set KillThreads to true and allow the message loop to end.

My general technique, rather than a simple boolean variable, would be to use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) as the signal for other threads to abort. The main reason for doing this is if I have long-running non-UI threads that want to sleep sometimes. By using the event, I can replace calls to `Thread.Sleep` with calls to `Event.WaitOne`, which means the thread will always wake up immediately if it has to abort.

---

In either case though, I don't usually wait around for the threads to signal completion. I trust them to do so in a timely manner, and don't tend to end up with subsequent code that relies on the threads not running. If you do have such a circumstance, perhaps you could elaborate on what it is?

Comment: thank you! I found one unsafe procedure with Invoke()'s in it and without try/catch.

Comment: And I think you're right, the problem is in unnecessary dependencies, I will use @Brian Gideon's advise in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Thread.Join` on all threads and kill via `Thread.Abort` if they couldn't be joined within a given timeout. The call of Abort raises a ThreadAbortException in the thread's context which ends this thread.

Comment: Thread.Abort isn't generally recommended, since the threads could be doing anything with global state when the rug is unceremoniously pulled from under them.

Comment: Yes, in deed. You have to be careful killing threads. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: @PVitt As I wrote, one of the threads is sending commands to external device, so killing the thread is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main point (whether the main thread is waiting for the other threads to end, or not) is to check if KillThreads is false, before invoking operations on the GUI thread, unless you really want to show something to the user just before exiting, in which case you should just loop in your main thread, checking ThreadState or IsAlive properties of all the worker threads, to determine, if they're already finished and then quit (or do whatever is needed after all the worker threads are done).

Comment: There's a race here - `T1` checks KillThreads, it's false. `MainThread` sets KillThreads to true. `MainThread` shuts down its message loop. `T1` calls `Invoke`.

Comment: You're right. To avoid that, he should use some locking mechanism as well, to prevent this race condition.